# Python flask auth special characters

Tags: python, flask, unicode

I have issue with passing special characters into basic http auth

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('RandomUser', 'SuperSecretPassword'))
```

It's okay.
But following code doesn't working

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('Michalčč', 'password'))
```

It returns

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(256)
```

And similar problem with returning from flask

```
return make_response(jsonify({'message': "Soutěž byla úspěšně odstraněna"}), 200)
```

Generally I have no  idea how working with special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('Michalčč'.encode('utf-8'), 'password'))
```

Try this, see if it works for you. I am no longer getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(256)
```